# React Bootstrap container different sizing to regular HTML Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

Why does the Bootstrap container component size differently than a regular HTML Bootstrap, not sure if I am missing a prop or not?

This is what I get the output I get for both:
(the white space in the sides are from the container margin)

[image]

React code:

```
<Container>
  <Row className="row">
    <Col className="col-lg-3 col-md-4">
      <div
        style={{ width: "100%", height: "100vh", backgroundColor: "blue" }}
      ></div>
    </Col>
    <div className="col-lg-9 col-md-8 tab-container">
        <div
            style={{ width: "100%", height: "100vh", backgroundColor: "red" }}
        ></div>
    </div>
  </Row>
</Container>
```

Regular HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4">
            <div style="width: 100%; height: 100vh; background-color: blue"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8">
            <div style="width: 100%; height: 100vh; background-color: red"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone help with the correct styling/fix for the React version to match the regular one please?

Comment: you have zoomed out in one of the screenshots

Comment: omfg I tried a bunch of things with the css and it turned out to be this lol. Thank you!